# Exception in Jersey Rest Service in Java - Weblogic Server 10.2.3

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, weblogic

I have created a rest service in Jersey which is internally using Jackson for mapping JSON to Java Object. The whole Service works on Apache tomcat but however when i deploy it on weblogic 10.2.3 it is giving the below error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.domain.pojo.CreateOutput.pcsetErrorText&#40;Ljava/lang/String&#59;&#41;V
at org.domain.pojo.CreateOutput.setErrorText(CreateEVCOutput.java)
at org.domain.serviceinterface.ExceptionMapper.toResponse(ExceptionMapper.java:14)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.mapException(ContainerResponse.java:480)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.mapMappableContainerException(ContainerResponse.java:417)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1477)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:184)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3732)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

I am using Jersey 1.19 and weblogic 10.2.3 version.

Below is my service class POST method

```
@POST
@Path("/post")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public CreateOutput RequestCall(Wrapper createServiceInput) {
    /*
     * handling all the business logic
     */
    CreateOutput serviceOutput = new CreateOutput();
    serviceOutput.setErrorCode("200");
    logger.info("Messafe Successfully Consumed without any exception");
    serviceOutput.setErrorText("Xml passed successfully");
    serviceOutput.setStatus("SUCCESS");
    // return HTTP response 200 in case of success
    return serviceOutput;
}
```

and below is my exception mapper custom class to handle exception

```
@Provider
public class MapperException implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {
CreateOutput createOutput = new CreateOutput();
public Response toResponse(Throwable e) {
    createOutput.setErrorText(e.getMessage());
    createOutput.setErrorCode(Status.PRECONDITION_FAILED.toString());
    createOutput.setStatus("failure");
    return Response.status(Status.PRECONDITION_FAILED).entity(createOutput).type("application/json").build();
}
```

}

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: I can see that you module has the method `org.domain.pojo.CreateOutput.setErrorText(CreateEVCOutput.java)`; while on WL it is searching for `org.domain.pojo.CreateOutput.pcsetErrorText`. Strange !!